# How to insert an column in csv file using python and adding value to it using loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, pandas

The original csv file has 100 rows. what I want is create a new column, and adding values from(1-24)and loop in.

Ex:

```
              New Row
1.               1
2.               2
3.               3
4.               4 
.
.
24               24
25               1

.
.
.
.
.
.
99                3
100               4
```

Comment: OK, and how did you approached to solve it, Your attempt as code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: We're not here to do all your work for you. Show us what you tried